# GSON could not convert generic <T> attribute

Tags: java, rest, generics, gson, json-deserialization

i currently use Google's GSON library to serialize/deserialize rest service responses. 
But i have a little problem. My response object has `T response` attribute.

```
public class IninalResponse<T> {

    private int httpCode;
    private String description;
    private T response;
    private HashMap<String,String> validationErrors;

    ...
}
```

I would like to get `response` attribute according to object type which i specified. At this example i specified with `GetAccessTokenResponse` to deserialize `T response` attribute in the piece of code below.

```
public IninalResponse getAccessToken(String apikey) {
    String path = "https://sandbox-api.ininal.com/v2/oauth/accesstoken";
    return doPostIninal(apikey,path,null,GetAccessTokenResponse.class);
}
```

[GSON library](https://github.com/google/gson) successfully deserializes `IninalResponse` object except for `T response` field. Gson deserializes it as `LinkedTreeMap` typed object.

```
public <T,V> IninalResponse doPostIninal(String apikey, String path,V requestBody, T response) {
    RestTemplate template = restClient.getRestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,apikey);
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.DATE, "");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");

    HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestBody,headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> accessTokenResponse = restClient.getRestTemplate().postForEntity(path,request,String.class);

    IninalResponse<T> responseBody = new IninalResponse<T>();
    responseBody = new Gson().fromJson(accessTokenResponse.getBody(),responseBody.getClass());
    System.out.println(accessTokenResponse);
    return responseBody;
}
```

Still i have no idea why gson could not deserialize ? What exactly am i missing ?

Comment: have a try: public <T> IninalResponse<T> getAccessToken(String apikey) and always assign the result of the method to a typed object such: InitialResponse<ValueX> v = getac

Answer (score 1):

Due to `Java`'s type erasure, you need to make a trick to serialize/deserialize generic types:

```
Type fooType = new TypeToken<IninalResponse<TheType>>() {}.getType();    
gson.fromJson(accessTokenResponse.getBody(), fooType);
```

where `TheType` is the type you passed in during serialization (`String` I suppose).

Serialization goes as this:

```
Type fooType = new TypeToken<IninalResponse<String>>() {}.getType(); // I assume it was a String here.    
gson.toJson(someString, fooType);
```